# Module level variable in Electron Preload file. How?

Tags: electron

I have a preload file of a child form. The parent form opens several instances of it and I want to keep tracking of each child form using an identifier (formid). The formid has to be in each preload file.

I tried declaring a module level variable called formid but it's not accessible in the various functions that I have. Here's some sample code from that the preload file.

```
let formid = 1;

let setformId = async (formi) => {
    formid = formi;

    
}

let checkFormId = () => {
    return formid;
}
```

I expected this to work, but it doesn't. What am I missing?

Comment: I also want to find out the answer for this. So far what worked for me is to put a variable in `main.index` (or at least referenced there). You can even do `console.log` easily. Of course you need to have a key to grab each window instance to make sure the variable only is valid for that instance. But i haven't figured out how to do it in `preload`, maybe this piece doesn't persist in memory.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found a way to retain the values in the renderer process using the preload.

```
ipcRenderer.on("startup", (event, formId) => {
    console.log("preloadBrowser > Startup > " + formId);

    contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld('Startup', { formId}); //formIdsaved here
})
```

What I am doing here is exposing the value in the main world in a Startup variable. Since the functions in the preload.js are called from the browser ui, I just pass it as a value to the preload.js function

It's not a solution I like, but this is a solution that's working for now.

Still looking for something better.